# Is there a site on ChemSE to practice mhchem and mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax, mhchem

Is there a site on ChemSE to practice mhchem and mathjax? Or does one just learn while asking or answering a question.

Comment: See also [Formatting Sandbox I (closed)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/111/7951) and [Formatting Sandbox II](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3077/7951)

Comment: It is now at [Formatting Sandbox III](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/). Formatting Sandbox II was closed.

Answer (score 5):

We have a couple of posts on meta where you can add an answer and edit as you wish. The first one has been closed because of the large number of answers, which makes editing very difficult as MathJax takes a long time to render. The second one may be found here:

- [Formatting Sandbox II: please test stuff here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3077/16683)

There is some guidance on how to use MathJax/mhchem:

- [mhchem manual by the author of the package](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/)
- [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)
- [What additional formatting features are available to MathJax (possibly via \require{})?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ)

Comment: It is now at [Formatting Sandbox III](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/). Formatting Sandbox II was closed.